# Why is upvoting being recommended here?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, review, new-users

I've just noticed that the full text you get on the First Posts review queue includes:

> When in doubt, upvote the question and leave a comment to help the user out, or click **Skip** if you are not sure and want to go to the next item.

Why on earth is it recommending upvoting if in doubt? Surely it should just read;

> If in doubt click **Skip** to go onto the next item.

While removing the text isn't going to stop all robo-reviewers it might stop a few and it will also remove the defence of "I was just doing what it said on the page" from the rest.

The Late Answers text just has short form.

Comment: Actually not only Late Answers' text is okay but also answers' text on First Post is okay.

Comment: @hims056 - Ah - a subtle distinction and thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Totally agree that it should be changed.. not that it makes much difference, I think the robo reviewers will upvote anything with or without such text. :/

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - good point, but at the moment they can say "the page told me I should upvote".

Comment: Not sure what I should do with this question so I upvoted it.

Comment: Where are you seeing that language?  I think that was already changed - on SU (the first site I found with a non-empty queue) I'm seeing, "When in doubt, click Skip if you are not sure and want to go to the next item."

Comment: @Jaydles - photography.

Comment: @Jaydles - and yes I know I should have taken a screen shot.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The original philosophy here was simple: if you can't find any problems with someone's first question, up-vote it.

It can be surprisingly hard to ask a good question on Stack Exchange, particularly for folks who've never been exposed to the system before. So giving a little pat on the back to those who manage to figure it out without tripping over their own feet half a dozen times first seemed appropriate.

It doesn't show up for answers, since there's a bit more to providing a good answer than just the form.

I haven't seen anyone use the argument that this is their pass to up-voting everything yet (I'd be a bit surprised if the folks doing the three-second reviews bothered reading it).

To clarify this intent, the guidance has been changed to:

> Be sure to **leave a comment** if you can help the user out, **upvote the question** if you can't find any problems with it, or click **Skip** if you are not sure and want to go to the next item.

Comment: It just struck me as odd and potentially - dangerous (though that's too strong a word really) and I thought it would have been changed with all the furore around robo-reviewers.

Comment: "if you can't find any problems with someone's first question, up-vote it." but that's not actually what the text *says*. It says, "if in doubt, upvote." You should change it to match your text.

Comment: @Jeff: yeah, that makes sense - done.

Comment: Yes! We should be kind. Else we are not human.